# Find the most frequent number in an array

Tags: java, array, hash-map

I implemented a solution for: Finding the most frequent number from an array. How are my variable names? Or how could I improve this?

```
 private static Integer findMostFrequentNumber(int[] givenArray) {
    int mostFrequentNumber = 0;
    if (givenArray != null) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> numberOccuranceMap = new HashMap<>();
        int mostFrequentOccurance = 0;

        for (Integer number : givenArray) {
            if (!numberOccuranceMap.containsKey(number)) {
                numberOccuranceMap.put(number, 1);
            } else {
                numberOccuranceMap.put(number, numberOccuranceMap.get(number) + 1);
            }
            if (numberOccuranceMap.get(number) > mostFrequentOccurance) {
                mostFrequentNumber = number;
                mostFrequentOccurance = numberOccuranceMap.get(number);
            }
        }
    }
    return mostFrequentNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a /** */ javadoc sentence, clarifying what happens in e.g. the case where { 5, 5, 6, 6 } is passed in.

The name `findMostFrequentNumber()` seems a bit verbose, when [`mode()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) or `findMode()` would suffice.

Consider `numbers` instead of `givenArray`. In any event, "array" is redundant with `int[]`.

Consider eliding the null check. Caller gets what he deserves if the [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) is "caller shall provide an array of numbers". NPE is appropriate if caller fails to do that. Or throw your own exception. Returning zero is clearly inappropriate, as caller cannot distinguish between an input of null and an input of { 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5 }.

In `numberOccuranceMap`, the "map" is redundant with the `Map` declaration. (Also, typo: occurrence.) Consider a "to" name for your maps, such as `numToOccurences` or `numToCount`.

```
    int mostFrequentOccurance = 0;
```

This sounds like it is simply `modeCount`, and the mostFrequentNumber we will return is simply `mode`.

```
            numberOccuranceMap.put(number, numberOccuranceMap.get(number) + 1);
```

Your `get()` call could specify a 2nd argument default value of zero, which would obviate the need for the containsKey() test.

```
        if (numberOccuranceMap.get(number) > mostFrequentOccurance) {
            mostFrequentNumber = number;
            mostFrequentOccurance = numberOccuranceMap.get(number);
        }
```

Here we find the answer to the javadoc question above: last one wins!